# CheckBox que seleciona todas

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma lista de várias checkbox, e queria que a ultima checkbox fosse para selecionar e des-selecionar todas as outras. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjnw4w3L/4/):

```js
if (document.getElementById("all").checked = true){
    //selecionar todas
}

if (document.getElementById("all").checked = false){
   //des-selecionar todas
}
```

```html
1<input type="checkbox"  id=1 name=1>
2<input type="checkbox"  name=2>
3<input type="checkbox"  name=3>
4<input type="checkbox"  name=4>
5<input type="checkbox"  name=5>
<p>Todas<input type="checkbox"  id=all name=all></p>
```

Comment: Esse exemplo também podia estar mais bem construído...

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida? É em como selecionar todas as checkboxes para marcação? É como fazer com que elas fiquem marcadas? Outra coisa?

Comment: é marcar e desmarcar todas as checkbox com apenas a ultima checkbox. Editei o jsfiddle.

Comment: @akm, já reparas-te que todo o teu html está mal construído? Falta as aspas " em cada elemento..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecione o *checkbox* desejado, e atribua-lhe a função `onclick`:

```
document.querySelector("input[name=all]").onclick = function() {
```

Selecione os demais *checkboxes* (no seu exemplo são todos, mas o ideal seria usar classes para isso):

```
    var lista = document.querySelectorAll("input");
```

Percorra-os

```
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < lista.length ; i++ )
```

E atribua sua propriedade `checked` para `true`.

```
        lista[i].checked = true;
};
```

[Exemplo completo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjnw4w3L/5/). Se em vez disso você quer tanto marcar quanto desmarcar (dependendo se a última está ou não marcada) então você precisa primeiro selecionar o valor novo:

```
document.querySelector("input[name=all]").onclick = function(e) {
    var marcar = e.target.checked; // A verificação ocorre depois que o valor já mudou
```

E então usá-lo nas outras *checkboxes*:

```
    var lista = document.querySelectorAll("input");
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < lista.length ; i++ )
        lista[i].checked = marcar;
};
```

[Exemplo atualizado](http://jsfiddle.net/fjnw4w3L/6/).

Comment: como eu poderia resolver esse meu http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178790/como-enviar-checkbox-com-names-diferentes-para-o-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer isso por Javascript, associando a acção a uma CheckBox principal que vai selecionar todas as outras. Segue exemplo, onde seleciona todas as CheckBox pela classe CSS `checkbox1`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="selecctall"/> Selecionar tudo
<br /><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item1"> Item 1
<br /><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item2"> Item 2
<br /><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item3"> Item 3
<br /><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item4"> Item 4
<br /><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item5"> Item 5
<br /><input class="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item6"> Item 6
<br /><input class="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="item6"> Esta não seleciona
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selecctall').click(function(event) {  //on click 
        if(this.checked) { // check select status
            $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            });
        }else{
            $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });         
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fjnw4w3L/3/

Answer (score 1):

Outros usuários já forneceram soluções interessantes, mas aqui vai uma alternativa caso ache interessante, vou colocar em javascript e jquery:

> Inversão de Seleções

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click', '#all', function (e) {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('#all').each(function() {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        checked ? $(this).prop('checked', false) : $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.getElementById("all").addEventListener("click", function(){
    checkBoxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not([id=all])');
    //"Hack": http://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/
    [].forEach.call(checkBoxs, function(checkbox) {
        checkbox.checked = checkbox.checked ? false : true;
    });
});
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lxwsae3/3/

### EDIT

> Selecionar/Deselecionar Todos

```
var checkedAll = false;

//JQUERY
$(document).on('click', '#all', function (e) {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('#all').each(function() {
        //Verificamos se é a hora de dar checked a todos ou tirar;
        checkedAll ? $(this).prop('checked', false) : $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
    //Invertemos ao final da execução, caso a última tenha sido true para checar todos, tornamos ele false para o próximo clique;
    checkedAll = checkedAll ? false : true;
});

//JAVASCRIPT
document.getElementById("all").addEventListener("click", function(){
    checkBoxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not([id=all])');
    //"Hack": http://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/
    [].forEach.call(checkBoxs, function(checkbox) {
        //Verificamos se é a hora de dar checked a todos ou tirar;
        checkbox.checked = checkedAll ? false : true;
    });
    //Invertemos ao final da execução, caso a última tenha sido true para checar todos, tornamos ele false para o próximo clique;
    checkedAll = checkedAll ? false : true;
});
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ze9qo4yu/1/

Caso tenha alguma dúvida ou não seja o que você procura, por favor avise.

Comment: Isso não vai simplesmente *inverter* a seleção de cada checkbox individual? O que o AP pediu foi que ao clicar em "todos" todos os demais fossem marcados ou desmarcados, independentemente de sua seleção atual.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Obrigado, bem observado, nem tinha percebido que fugi da pergunta, vou fazer mais um exemplo voltado a necessidade do usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido:

```
function marcarTodos(marcar){
    var itens = document.querySelectorAll("input");

    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<itens.length;i++){
        itens[i].checked = marcar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const check1 = document.querySelector('#check1')
const checkElements = document.querySelectorAll('form [type="checkbox"]');


check1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  checkElements.forEach((item) => {
    if (check1.checked) {
      item.checked = true;
    } else {
      item.checked = false
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form">
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check1" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check2" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check3" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check4" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" id="check5" />
    </form>    
  </body>
</html>
```